# How to access applicationDidEnterBackground from viewController

Tags: ios, appdelegate

How can I call `applicationDidEnterBackground` that in `AppDelegate` from a `viewController`?

I want to run a function in the background of the app without pressing home button.

Answer (score 13):

You are not supposed to call that function from anywhere. It is there to let you know when the app enters the background.

Do you simply want to know when the app enters the background? If so, then you can create a notification to help you with that:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self
                                         selector: @selector(handleEnteredBackground:) 
                                             name: UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
                                           object: nil];
```

Comment: I want to run a function in the background of the app without pressing home button

Comment: Then you need to learn about background tasks: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW20

Comment: @joelg when do you unsubscribe from the notification though? do you remove all subscribers in didTerminate?

Comment: Undeclared selector 'handleEnteredBackground:' warning there how and where should I declare would you update your question plz

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 4**

To run something in your view controller when the app goes into background (typically you would save some user data):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { (notification) in
        print("app did enter background")

        // run your code here (or whatever)
    }

    // ...

}
```

Comment: This worked fine for me, just what I was looking for in my code to resolve a Tab Bar  jumping up further into screen when putting the app in the background while is was hidden. I just placed a function linking to make the Tab Bar reappear when closing the app and all was then sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { (notification) in
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a delegate method. You should not call this method manually. If you want to call the code return in this method. You should create a function and move the code there. Then you should call this function.

Comment: I want to run a function in the background of the app without pressing home button

Comment: use performselectorinbackground method

Answer (score 0):

This is another way and it'll run on background also
Generally, you register the notification first, in your viewController.m init method (or somewhere else appropriate):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self
                                         selector: @selector(someMethod:) 
                                             name: @"NotificationNameHere"
                                           object: nil];
```

In your App Delegate, fire the notification:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification: @"NotificationNameHere"];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should register a notification in its viewDidLaod method.

'UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification' will automatically notify your application and given controller, if they have registered for.

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(yourMethod)
                                             name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

In your ViewController

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@property AppDelegate *appDelegate;
```

In your viewDidLoad

```
appDelegate=[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

To call the functions from AppDelegate

```
 [appDelegate applicationDidEnterBackground:[UIApplication sharedApplication]];
```

Answer (score 0):

In your ViewController

## import "AppDelegate.h"

@property AppDelegate *appDelegate;
In your viewDidLoad

_appDelegate=[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
To call the functions from AppDelegate

[_appDelegate applicationDidEnterBackground:[UIApplication sharedApplication]];

Comment: You can use code blocks for code. It looks and reads better. :)

Answer (score -1):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate applicationDidEnterBackground: [UIApplication sharedApplication]]
```

Comment: Error in this line. (No known instance method for selector applicationDidEnterBackground)

Comment: sorry I forgot the parameter